# Angular 12 how to get a value for environment value through a function

Tags: angular, production-environment

I have the need to do something like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: this.setUrl()
};
```

so that on startup setUrl would be called and assign the returned value to serverUrl, how can I do this or something that basically does this without using anything other than the angular project itself?

Answer (score 2):

You need a few enviroment.ts configurations, like enviroment.prod.ts

So you can set different serverUrl for each.

On build you use a flag -configuration=prod

Comment: can you give me a snippet of that?

Comment: Create a new files on enviroment folder in /src/enviroments
enviroment.stag.ts
enviroment.prod.ts
enviroment.ts (should exists)

```export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: "https://google.com"
};```

And change serverURL in each file.

At build you can use the flag like i said.

```ng serve --configuration=prod```
```ng serve --configuration=stag```

Answer (score 0):

done, here's what I did:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpXhrBackend } from "@angular/common/http";

export const environmentProd = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: setUrl()
};

function setUrl() :string {
  let http = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend({ 
    build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() 
  }));
  return "whatever"
}
```

now I'll use the httpClient to get a txt file from the app itself, I read it's content as a megaString and then I can play with it as I see fit. (evil laugh here)

EDIT:
this thing only works until you refresh the page, but I did manage to do what I needed in an easy and clean way following this tutorial:
https://www.technouz.com/5125/changing-angular-environment-variables-at-runtime/

Comment: Just because you can, doesn’t mean you should ..